# Как скопировать View

Tags: android, view

Есть View которое создается через inflater из xml файла. Таких View нужно создать много. И чтобы не прогонять каждое через inflater как создать копию View из уже созданного?

Comment: По-видимому никак

Comment: Если сложная `ViewGroup`, лучше создавать программно. Если простая, то можно и `inflate` оставить.

Comment: Напишите больше подробностей о сути задачи. Вполне возможно найдется более простое и конкретное решение.

Answer (score 0):

Чисто технически это возможно, но лучше использовать уже готовые системные решения - `RecyclerView`. Этот класс имеет почти 13 000 строк и делает как раз то, что вам нужно - использует ранее загруженные `View` вместо загрузки новых при прокрутке списка.